# R_SH_GOT32 unexpected by Android loader for atomic exchange()

Tags: c++11, android-ndk, g++, atomic

My device fails to load native library; the error message is

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: unknown reloc type 160 @ 0xa849dc64 (6010)
```

actually `160` is **`R_SH_GOT32`** and should not be expected by Android loader.

This is the minimal code sample:

```
#include <atomic>
#define N 3
struct S {
    int a[N];
};

void qq() {
    std::atomic<S> s;
    s.exchange(S());
}
```

Note that it is enough to `#define N 2` for the library to load correctly.

I am using NDK `r10e`, testing on ARM 32 with emulator set to API 4.4.4 (API 19). I tried different toolchains: 4.8, 4.9, and clang. I tried gnustl_static and shared, and libc++, too.

*Does this smell like a bug in NDK?*

**Update**: with NDK 11, and clang toolchain, the linker simply shows

> NDK_ROOT/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/atomic:233: error: undefined reference to '__atomic_exchange'

Comment: Just encountered the same issue (library fails to load when using std::atomic<T>, where sizeof(T) = 4*sizeof(float)).  Android NDK r10e, toolchain version 4.9, STL: gnustl_shared.

Answer (score 0):

For atomic support on android :

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html

Google fixed atomic lib in NDK 12 (GCC)
Atomic support : 
If you include , it's likely that you also need libatomic. If you are using ndk-build, add the following line:

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -latomic
If you are using your own toolchain, use:

-latomic

Try this, it should solve linking issues.

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same issue with ndk r10e. But my library was loading correctly, issue appeared in runtime.

The problem was solved when I switched to clang 3.5 in ndk r10c.

Comment: This does not help in my case; maybe your code is slightly different? Can you share a minimal piece that links, and but fails at runtime, and gets fixed with switch to clang 3.5?